# Can not create initial context in java program

Tags: java, java-deployment-toolkit, noinitialcontextexception

```
public static void setupInitialContext() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Loading Initial Context");
        NamingManager.setInitialContextFactoryBuilder(new InitialContextFactoryBuilder() {

            @Override
            public InitialContextFactory createInitialContextFactory(Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
                    throws NamingException {
                return new InitialContextFactory() {
                    @Override
                    public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws NamingException {
                        InitialContext context = null;

                        try {
                            context = new MockLocalContext();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return context;
                    }

                };
            }

        });
        System.out.println("Loaded Initial Context");
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    setupInitialContext();
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    context.lookup(DS_ORACLE);
}
```

MockLocalContext is a class which extendes javax.naming.InitialContext class.
and this is error while creating object of InitialContext.

I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getJndiProperties(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext.<init>(MockLocalContext.java:97)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext.<init>(MockLocalContext.java:95)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext$3$1.getInitialContext(MockLocalContext.java:400)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext.<init>(MockLocalContext.java:97)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext.<init>(MockLocalContext.java:95)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext$3$1.getInitialContext(MockLocalContext.java:400)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext.<init>(MockLocalContext.java:97)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext.<init>(MockLocalContext.java:95)
at net.citigroup.mexico.pg.pgs.mock.MockLocalContext$3$1.getInitialContext(MockLocalContext.java:400)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

It goes one for many lines with the same content, I just trimmed it to fit in here. Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: can you show more of the stacktrace?

Comment: The above error. please find out.

Comment: do you have a recursive call somewhere in your code?

Comment: no, when i call setupInitialContext() method the above error occurs,

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your MockLocalContext initiates an InitialContext, which tries to get the default initial context which is a MockLocalContext, which initiates MockLocalContext, which initiates an InitialContext, and so on, and so on.

Comment: yes, but same code runs on a different machine and there give no error.

Comment: There might be a different default initial context on that other machine.

Comment: How its possible.. can you explain to me what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyContext extends InitialContext {

private Hashtable store;

public MyContext(Hashtable store) throws NamingException {
    super(true);
    this.store = store;
}

@Override
public void bind(String name, Object obj) {
    store.put(name, obj);
}

@Override
public Object lookup(String name) {
    return store.get(name);
}
```

}

```
public class FooMain {

private static final int    ANSWER    = 42;
private static final String JNDI_NAME = "/config/theAnswerToEverything";

public static void main (String args[]) throws NamingException {
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    putInContext(                    JNDI_NAME, ANSWER);

    int answer = retrieveFromContext(JNDI_NAME);
    Assert.assertEquals(ANSWER, answer);
    System.out.printf("%d\n", answer);
}


private static void putInContext(final String key, final Object value) throws NamingException {
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    context.bind(key, value);
}

private static int retrieveFromContext(final String key) throws NamingException {
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    return (int) context.lookup(key);
}}


public class MyContextFactory implements InitialContextFactory {

private static Hashtable store = new Hashtable();

/*
  Do not confuse [store] with [environment]. They serve different
  purposes.
 */

@Override
public Context getInitialContext(Hashtable environment) throws NamingException {
    return new MyContext(store);
}}

this code is used to remove error while creating an InitialContext the code goes recursively...
```

the constructor should be true while Extends InitialContext.